# Color from hex string in jetpack compose

Tags: android, android-jetpack-compose

How to parse hex string e.g. `#9CCC65` in [Color](https://cs.android.com/androidx/platform/frameworks/support/+/androidx-master-dev:ui/ui-graphics/src/main/java/androidx/ui/graphics/Color.kt) class in jetpack compose.

**P.S: option seem to be missing in jetpack compose package**

---

**Current Workaround:**
Exported `parseColor()` method from standard Color class.

```
@ColorInt
fun parseColor(@Size(min = 1) colorString: String): Int {
    if (colorString[0] == '#') { // Use a long to avoid rollovers on #ffXXXXXX
        var color = colorString.substring(1).toLong(16)
        if (colorString.length == 7) { // Set the alpha value
            color = color or -0x1000000
        } else require(colorString.length == 9) { "Unknown color" }
        return color.toInt()
    }
    throw IllegalArgumentException("Unknown color")
}
```

Comment: Parse the hex string into a `Long`. Pass that `Long` into the `Color()` function.

Comment: @CommonsWare tried exporting the `parseColor()` method from standard Color class. As its working fine for now, but I think jetpack compose team should add this method.

Comment: @CommonsWare tried your solution as well, having `java.lang.NumberFormatException` exception.

Comment: If you literally tried parsing `#9CCC65`, that will not work, as `#` is not part of a number. The algorithm is pretty much what you see there with `parseColor()`. I won't argue if the Compose team adds support for color strings like this, but I also would not be surprised if they decide that this is out of scope and can be handled easily enough by apps, or by some other non-Compose library.

Comment: @CommonsWare yeah got your point. Thanks!

Answer (score 64, accepted):

You can use this object class with a getColor method.

```
object HexToJetpackColor {
    fun getColor(colorString: String): Color {
            return Color(android.graphics.Color.parseColor("#" + colorString))
    }
}
```

Or we can use an extension function

```
fun Color.Companion.fromHex(colorString: String) = Color(android.graphics.Color.parseColor("#" + colorString))
```

Jetpack Color class i.e `androidx.ui.graphics.Color` only takes RGB, ARGB, ColorSpace and colorInt in constructor. See: `Color.kt`

so, here we are directly accessing `parseColor()` method from `android.graphics.Color` which returns colorInt.

Hence parseColor() method can be used to get colorInt and then providing it to Jetpack Color class to get `androidx.ui.graphics.Color` object.

Comment: Or maybe you can add an extension function in your project.

    fun Color.fromHex(color: String) = Color(android.graphics.Color.parseColor("#" + colorString))

Comment: @facundomr Well you should use Color.Companion instead of just Color, to use it in `Color.fromString()` form.

Comment: This does not take into count the transparency! It uses the last 6 characters, thus changing the color if there is transparency prefix!

Answer (score 101):

Instead of passing as String instead pass as Hexadecimal. For example if you want this `#9CCC65` Color just remove the front `#` and replace it with 0xFF. Example

```
val PrimaryBlue = Color(0xFF9CCC65)
```

Comment: This answer is not relevant as the question clearly mentioned to parse the string as color at runtime.

Comment: sorry i didn't saw anywhere that we have to parse at runtime

Comment: This answer is the best, because I was looking for this solution and I came to this question first.

Comment: I spent way too long on this just to realize I was adding 0x and not 0xff .... Don't be like me everyone.

Comment: There is an answer which is an answer to a better phrased question and this is it! Thanks @MayankWadhwa

Answer (score 22):

Similar to `Int.dp`, there can be `String.color` extenstion property.

```
val String.color 
    get() = Color(android.graphics.Color.parseColor(this))
```

This can be used as member property on color hex `String`.

```
"#FF0000".color
```

Answer (score 20):

I also had this problem and I finally found the solution:

```
    val myColorString = "#B00020"
    val myComposeColorInt = Color(myColorString.toColorInt())
```

Comment: Working and simple soultion

Comment: Just a note: toColorInt() calls android.graphics.Color.parseColor() under the hood, so this can't be used in regular unit tests.

Answer (score 19):

hex string to color [this extension function is available inside android sdk
]

```
Color("#FFFFFF".toColorInt())
```

incase if u want to convert back to hex code

```
fun Color.toHexCode(): String {
    val red = this.red * 255
    val green = this.green * 255
    val blue = this.blue * 255
    return String.format("#%02x%02x%02x", red.toInt(), green.toInt(), blue.toInt())
}
```

incase if u also want alpha value

```
fun Color.toHexCodeWithAlpha(): String {
            val alpha = this.alpha*255
            val red = this.red * 255
            val green = this.green * 255
            val blue = this.blue * 255
            return String.format("#%02x%02x%02x%02x", alpha.toInt(),red.toInt(), green.toInt(), blue.toInt())
        }
```

---

If we are in compose multi platform or in jvm based unit test then `toColorInt()` extension wont be available, you can use this instead

```kotlin
//source code from androidX 
fun String.toColorInt(): Int {
    if (this[0] == '#') {
        var color = substring(1).toLong(16)
        if (length == 7) {
            color = color or 0x00000000ff000000L
        } else if (length != 9) {
            throw IllegalArgumentException("Unknown color")
        }
        return color.toInt()
    }
    throw IllegalArgumentException("Unknown color")
}
```

Answer (score 13):

Another option is to write an extension function similar to how android.graphics.Color works:

```
import androidx.compose.ui.graphics.Color

fun Color.Companion.parse(colorString: String): Color =
    Color(color = android.graphics.Color.parseColor(colorString))
```

Then you can write your compose like this:

```
Modifier.background(Color.parse("#FF0000"))
```

Comment: This way makes the most sense syntactically imo.

Answer (score 12):

How about solution not dependant on Android? #KMP

```
val hashColorString = "#00AB18"
val color = Color(hashColorString.removePrefix("#").toLong(16) or 0x00000000FF000000)
```

Comment: This doesn't work. Try it with "#FFFFFF" and you won't get white.

Comment: You are right. I fixed it :)

Answer (score 3):

If you want to avoid having to import `android.graphics.Color`, here's another straightforward alternative:

```kotlin
val hexString = "#f8f8f2"
Color(("ff" + hexString.removePrefix("#").lowercase()).toLong(16))
```

`Color` in this case would be immediately the one from `androidx.compose.ui.graphics.Color`.

Comment: This doesn't work. Try it with "#ffffff" and you won't get white.

Comment: I just tried it with `ffffff` and `#ffffff`, and they both work, @Bartek. The white colour was shown. This is the exact code I'm running:

`fun hexToColor(hexString: String): Color { return Color(("ff" + hexString.removePrefix("#").lowercase()).toLong(16)) }`

Are you sure you didn't make a mistake elsewhere in your code?

Comment: the answer got fixe and now it works correctly