# how to transform from string to Color android

Tags: android, kotlin, android-jetpack-compose

I need to convert an string to Color my api response is this `"mainColor": "#8439FF"`, i need to transformit to Color

i have tried the next solutions

```
    int color = Color.parseColor(mainColor);

val string = mainColor
val ColorPrimario = string.replaceFirst("^#".toRegex(), "").toInt(16)
```

the problem whit this solutions is that the result its an int not Color, and it marks error for that reason. any help would be appreciated

-------------Edit-------------

I have solved the problem i did it this way

```
val string = mainColor
val color = Color(string.toColorInt())
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Color from hex string in jetpack compose](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60247480/color-from-hex-string-in-jetpack-compose)

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
val color: Color = Color.valueOf(Color.parseColor(mainColor))
```

See https://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/Color#valueOf(int)

Comment: tried this but the editor tells me that valueOf and paseColor are unresolved reference

Comment: @user10625391 You need to import `android.graphics.Color`. This *is* how you do it - parse the string to a colour int, then use that colour int to create a `Color` instance